# LaTeX Warning: Reference undefined

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

My document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

As known, 
\begin{equation} 
    \label{trivial} 
    7\times9=63. 
\end{equation}
It follows from the formula (\ref{trivial}) that $63/9=7$. 

\end{document}
```

My warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `trivial' on page 1 undefined on input line 9.
```

My PDF:

```
... from the formula (??) that ...
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: Did you do the second compilation? Or are you using a tool like `latexmk` that automates the process?

Comment: Label information is saved in an `.aux` file in the first run, but is not available to a reference in that run.  In subsequent runs, the `.aux` file is read back in, and references are resolved.  By the way, if you use the `amsmath` package, you can use `\eqref{<label>}` to produce the equation number already wrapped in parentheses.

Comment: To get pdf I have used command `pdflatex main.tex` If to replace it to `latexmk -pdf`
mistake disappears. Thanks a lot!